# Problem integrating Yale CAS with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I downloaded the sample ASP.NET login page from here:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/ASP.NET+Forms+Authentication

And got CAS working with a proof-of-concept ASP.NET site very quickly.  Now that I am trying to use this login page with SharePoint 2010, I am having a hard time.  After the redirect line:
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(SSOUsername, false);

I get "403 Unauthorized."

Any ideas?

Thanks.  Has anyone gotten the CAS SSO to work with SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(SSOUsername, false) will not work with Claims authentication. It was used for the older ASP.net authentication. To log in with claims used SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(url, username, password). This will require a password unlike forms authentication.